# Artifactory Configuration in Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to configure the Artifactory in Jenkins Pipeline Job. I am referring to JFROG documentation for the same which mentions 3 ways to instantiate artifactory object:

```
def server = Artifactory.server 'my-server-id'
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'artifactory-url', username: 'username', password: 'password'
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'artifactory-url', credentialsId: 'ccrreeddeennttiiaall'
```

We can use any of the above ways and after getting the `buildInfo` which we want to publish in artifactory we do

```
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

This step is causing exception for whci th stacktrace below-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfoAccessor.createDeployer(BuildInfoAccessor.java:75)
at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:59)
at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:39)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:42)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:184)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.ArtifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo(ArtifactoryServer.java:132)
at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.ArtifactoryServer$publishBuildInfo.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:26)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3452.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4288.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

UPDATE 1:

```
node {
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: SERVER_URL, credentialsId: CREDENTIALS
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

stage 'Build'
    git url: 'https://github.com/jfrogdev/project-examples.git'

stage 'Artifactory configuration'
    rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL // Tool name from Jenkins configuration
    rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
    rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-release', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot', server: server
    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

stage 'Publish build info'
    server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo}
```

`NullPointerException` is caused by the last statement `server.publishbuildInfo buildInfo`. So i think i am not getting the Artifactory Server Instance.

UPDATE 2:

I was able to resolve the above issues by passing the correct credentials. But now when i am trying to deploy the artifacts to Artifactory repository then getting the following exception:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified method org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.deployers.MavenDeployer deployArtifacts org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:113)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:36)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3452.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4288.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post the reason why it is failing form your Jenkins build log?

Comment: @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial I have updated the question.

Comment: I was asking for the Failure log of your pipeline job.

Comment: @ANILMAHAPATRAOfficial yes the log that I have posted in the question is failure log of pipeline job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent some time researching this issue myself, I think you're hitting the same problem I saw which is supposed to be fixed [JENKINS-37129](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37129). Namely: the method `deployArtifacts` isn't defined in `org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.deployers.MavenDeployer` in the version of the plugin you're using.

The functionality to allow discrete build/publish steps was added in v2.12.0 of the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins with issue [HAP-919](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-919). Per the release history, that was let loose into the wild on [June 29](https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin/releases/tag/artifactory-2.12.0), but my Jenkins administrator hasn't seen fit to upgrade yet. If you've got access to do so, I'd suggest upgrading the plugin version to see if it solves your issue.

Hope this helps!